# How to request financial data from Yahoo's YQL and Quandl?

Tags: finance, data-acquisition, webservices, json-format

How can I download historical data from Yahoo ? Although Mathematica's FinancialData function uses Yahoo it could be useful to have more control on how to retrieve data from Yahoo's YQL.

**Edit** Similarly how could I use Quandl ?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3117/66 , http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28053/66

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's a set of functions that allows to do this. The code uses many ideas found on this site and on other places on the web. It is a bit factorized already so it should be easily reusable.

More on YQL and available tables here:
https://developer.yahoo.com/yql
https://github.com/yql
[Query test](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=desc%20yahoo.finance.quotes&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.historicaldata+where+symbol+in+%28%22YHOO%22%29+and+startDate+%3D+%222014-04-15%22+and+endDate+%3D+%222014-04-18%22)

**Edit**: this API is great also and simple http://www.quandl.com/help/api
You get usable data in MM and some basic data manipulation straight away using

```
Import@"http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.csv?sort_order=asc&exclude_headers=true&rows=3&trim_start=2012-11-01&trim_end=2013-11-30&column=4&collapse=quarterly&transformation=rdiff"
```

The work below is still useful in order to access other types of data than financial ones in YQL.
Here are usage examples

```
symbol="YHOO";
symbols={"YHOO","GE"};
startDate={2013,04,13};
endDate={2014,04,16};

GetYahooMultiQuote[symbol,startDate,endDate]
GetYahooMultiQuote[symbols,startDate,endDate,{"Adj_Close","High"}]
```

Note that if you request too much data you won't be able to query too many symbols at the same time. But it's still quite practical to be able to get data for many symbols in only one request for a small historical time range.

```
toYahooString[string_String]:="\""<>string<>"\"";
toYahooDate[date_List]:=DateString[date,{"Year", "-","Month","-","Day"}]//toYahooString;
toYahooList[list_List]:=StringJoin@@Riffle[toYahooString/@list,","];
toYahooUrl[sqlRequest_String]:=
    Module[{urlRules},

        urlRules={" "->"%20","\""->"%22","("->"%28",")"->"%29"};

        StringReplace[
            "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json&q="
            <>sqlRequest
            ,
            urlRules
        ]
    ];
toYahooRequest[sqlRequest_]:=sqlRequest//toYahooUrl//Import[#,"JSON"]&;
doAndParseYahooRequest[sqlRequest_,yahooResultField_,requiredFields_,nsymbols_]:=
    Module[{jsonImport,quotes},

        jsonImport=sqlRequest//toYahooRequest;

        quotes=OptionValue[jsonImport,yahooResultField];

        requiredFields/.quotes // Partition[#,Length@#/nsymbols]& // If[Length@#==1,First@#,#]&
    ];

possibleQuotes=Alternatives@@{"Adj_Close","Close","Date","High","Low","Open","Symbol","Volume"};

ClearAll@GetYahooMultiQuote;
GetYahooMultiQuote[symbols_,startDate_,endDate_,quote:(possibleQuotes|{possibleQuotes..}):"Adj_Close"]:=
    Module[{symbols2=Flatten@{symbols},sqlRequest,sqlRequestModified},

        sqlRequest="select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol in (SYMBOLS) and startDate = START_DATE and endDate = END_DATE";
        sqlRequestModified=
            StringReplace[
                sqlRequest
                ,
                {"SYMBOLS"->toYahooList@symbols2,"START_DATE"->toYahooDate@startDate,"END_DATE"->toYahooDate@endDate}
            ];

        doAndParseYahooRequest[sqlRequestModified,"query"->"results"->"quote",quote,Length@symbols2]
    ];
```

**Edit**

For Quandl the following function is useful. It implements all the importing options described in the help http://www.quandl.com/help/api. It works for a single set or a multiset. It includes memoization also.

```
(*"transformation=none|diff|rdiff|cumul|normalize"
"collapse=none|daily|weekly|monthly|quarterly|annual"
"sort_order=asc|desc"
"dataFormat=csv|json|xml"*)

ClearAll@GetQuandlData;
Options[GetQuandlData]={"Collapse"->"daily","Tansformation"->"none","Sort"->"asc","ExcludeHeaders"->True,"Column"->4,"DataFormat"->"csv","Token"->None};
GetQuandlData[ticker_,nData:({startDate_,endDate_}|rows_),opts:OptionsPattern[]]:= GetQuandlData[ticker,nData,opts]=
Module[{dataFormat,collapse,transformation,sort,url,excludeHeaders,column,token},
    {dataFormat,collapse,transformation,sort,excludeHeaders,column,token}=
        OptionValue[GetQuandlData,#]&/@{"DataFormat","Collapse","Tansformation","Sort","ExcludeHeaders","Column","Token"};

    url="https://www.quandl.com/api/v1/"~~
        If[ListQ@ticker,
            "multisets."~~
            dataFormat~~
            "?columns="~~
            StringJoin@@
                Riffle[
                    MapThread[
                        #1~~"."~~#2&
                        ,
                        {StringReplace[#,"/"->"."]&/@ticker,ToString/@If[ListQ@column,column,ConstantArray[column,Length@ticker]]}
                    ]
                    ,
                    ","
                ]
            ,
            "datasets/"~~
            ticker~~
            "."~~
            dataFormat~~
            "?"~~
            If[column===All,
                ""
                ,
                "column="~~
                ToString@column
            ]
        ]~~
        "&collapse="~~
        collapse~~
        If[ListQ@nData,
            "&trim_start="~~
            DateString[startDate,{"Year","-","Month","-","Day"}]~~
            "&trim_end="~~
            DateString[endDate,{"Year","-","Month","-","Day"}]
            ,
            "&rows="~~
            ToString@rows
        ]~~
        "&sort_order="~~
        sort~~
        "&transformation="~~
        transformation~~
        "&exclude_headers="~~
        ToString@excludeHeaders~~
        If[token===None,
            ""
            ,
            "&auth_token="~~
            token
        ];

    Import@url
];

GetQuandlData["YAHOO/INDEX_GSPC", {{2014, 08, 16}, {2014, 10, 16}}, "Tansformation"->"diff"]  
GetQuandlData["YAHOO/INDEX_VIX",10,"Sort"->"desc"]  
GetQuandlData[{"YAHOO/INDEX_GSPC", "YAHOO/INDEX_VIX"},10,"Sort"->"desc","Column"->{4,2}]  
GetQuandlData[{"YAHOO/INDEX_GSPC", "YAHOO/INDEX_VIX"},10,"Sort"->"desc","Column"->4]
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5246843/884752

Comment: Unfortunately, as of approximately May 2017, this will no longer work.  Will return `The server returned the HTTP status code 400 ("Bad Request"`

Comment: Quandl still works though.

Answer (score 4):

You can find QuandlLink package for Mathematica from following wolfram community post:

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/540228

or

https://github.com/bajracha71/Quandl-Mathematica-QuandlLink

Answer (score 4):

Just for Quandl.
You can use [Quandl's API guide](https://blog.quandl.com/getting-started-with-the-quandl-api) and customize the data. For example, first download historical data for FaceBook.

```
stDate = "2015-05-31";
endDate = "2017-05-31";
mysymbol = "WIKI/FB";
yourapikey = "..."; (*you need to supply your freely available quandl api key*)
data = Import[StringJoin["https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/", mysymbol, 
    "/data.csv?start_date=", stDate, "&end_date=", endDate, 
    "&order=asc&api_key=", yourapikey]];
First[data]
```

Then convert "Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume" into a time seires.

```
dates = ToExpression[StringSplit[data[[2 ;;, 1]], "-"]];
datav = data[[2 ;;, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]];
datats = TimeSeries[datav, {dates}];
```

Then you can use `TradingChart` to chart the data.

```
TradingChart[datats]
```

[image]