# Missing elements using FinancialData

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data, finance

I have a list of stock symbols which I selected with `FinancialData["Menbers"]` that looks like the following list:

```
allIndices={"^AGG-EU", "^AGG-IV", "^AGG-NV", "^AGG-SO","^EBT-SO"}
```

Now I would like to load the related name and exchange of these symbols using the following function:

```
indexMasterData =
  DeleteCases[
   Map[
    {FinancialData[#, "Symbol"], FinancialData[#, "Name"], 
      FinancialData[#, "Exchange"]}
     &, allIndices],
   {___, _Missing, ___} (* eliminates nested lists with Missing[
   "NotAvailable"] entries *)
   ];
```

The problem is, that *Mathematica* obviuosly does not know all symbols (even if the FinancialData function provides these symbols] and I get the following error message:

> FinancialData::notent: "^EBT-SO" is not a known entity, class, or tag
>   for "FinancialData".  ... General::stop: "Further output of
>   "FinancialData::notent will be suppressed during this calculation"

Why does *Mathematica* not know these elements anymore? How can I skip/ignore these elements in my function?

Comment: In my experience, the output of FinancialData (which is determined from calls to Yahoo finance) is rather unreliable. Calls that yieled data at one time, may return Missing some time later. For instance, a call like `FinancialData["^GSPC", "Members"]` used in the examples doesn't work for me at the time of writing.

Comment: Yes, I've found the same @SjoerdC.deVries. I created a list of tickers two months back (for which data could be collected). When I run it now, there are plenty of errors.

Comment: this will help http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46760/66

Comment: Warning:  This stuff does not work any better in the Wolfram Finance Platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, those are not stock symbols. Tickers starting with ^ are indexes. (As an example, ^NYA is the [NYSE Composite](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=%5ENYA&ql=0).)

I've found that when a ticker is not recognized, it's usually a "weird" ticker. I can not find ^EBT-SO on Yahoo Finance, while I can find ^AGG-EU. So ^EBT-SO is supposed to be an index, but unclear from where and what it measures. It's probably useless for your application, and can be discarded.

I run a test to see whether the data can be collected:

```
test = Quiet[Check[
   propertyReturn = FinancialData[name, type];
   , False]
];
If[test == False || propertyReturn == Missing["NotAvailable"],
 Return[{}],
 0
];
```

If data could not be collected {} is returned, else you can go ahead and return the data.